# Existence of curve that passes only through strictly irrational points

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $n \geq 2$. I define a strictly irrational point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as one where all the coordinates are irrational. The question is, is there a continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing at least two points (either open curve or closed curve) that contains only strictly irrational points?

Comment: Isn't the curve then continuous separately in each co-ordinate, and the intermediate value theorem ensures some rational value for any co-ordinate on which the function is not constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This follows from the intermediate value theorem.

For consider points $p_0 \neq p_1$ on the curve. Since they are not equal, take $i$ such that the $i$th component of $p_0$ and $p_1$ are not equal. Since the $i$th component of $p_0$ and $p_1$ are distinct, take a rational number $q$ which is strictly between them.

WLOG, suppose $\gamma$ is the curve and $\gamma(0) = p_0$ and $\gamma(1) = p_1$. Define $f(x) = $ the $i$th component of $\gamma(x)$. Then $f$ is continuous. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $x \in (0, 1)$ such that $f(x) = q$. Then $\gamma(x)$ is not totally irrational, since its $i$th component is $q$.

Edit: On the other hand, if you're looking for a curve where at least one point is irrational, just take the curve $\gamma(t) = (t, \sqrt [3]{1 - t^3})$ with domain $[1/3, 2/3]$. It cannot be the case that both coordinates are rational, since each $\gamma(t) = (x, y)$ solves $x^3 + y^3 = 1$ and there is no nontrivial rational solution to this equation by Fermat's Last Theorem.